# Can a UWP app service have a user interface?

Tags: uwp, ipc

I would like two UWP apps that have UI to communicate with each other.

I've been looking at [app services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but it says "App services let you create UI-less services" which suggests app services can't have UIs?

I've been messing around with the [AppServices sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices), but haven't figure out how to give the app service a UI.

Can an app service have UI?  If so, how?

---

**Edit**

I would like to have 2 UWP apps, App1 and App2.

App1 should be able to launch and close App2.

App1 should be able to query App2 for information.

App1 should be informed if App2 is closed by the user.

How can I achieve this app to app communication?

I have been looking at making App2 an app service, but am unsure how to make App2 a service but still have a UI.

Comment: Instead of creating console application create a WPF application. You can now have a UI All other API required are same

Comment: An app service is meant to be used by an app that has a GUI. The service can either run in the same process as the host GUI app or in a separate background process depending on your requirements. What problem are you trying to solve with an app service? If you need it to have a UI, why don't you implement the logic in the app itself?

Comment: @mm8  I've added some clarification the question.

Comment: @Vignesh  I'm not sure I understand :/  In the [AppService sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices) there are 3 projects:  `AppServicesProvider` (UWP app), `RandomNumberService` (Windows Runtime Component), and `AppServicesClient` (UWP app).  There is no console application. Also I am restricted to use UWP, so I cannot use WPF.

Comment: Like I said, an app services runs as part of an app that has a GUI. The service itself doesn't need a UI. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to launch an app from another app, you should register it to become the default handler for a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) scheme as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

You can then launch it from the other app using the [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) API.

An app cannot close another app directly, but you might send some data to other app to tell it to close.

This may for example be achieved using an [app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN). [This](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/#HRcvwPB8LCJCHJbQ.97) blog post about cross-app communication should get you started.

You might also want to read [this](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/#ChuEYPm9XxVY2ibu.97) blog post about sharing local app data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  I think I'll try have App2 have an in process app service, and app one launch App2 via `LaunchUriAsync` and communicate with App2 via the app service :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can an app service have UI? If so, how?

You could create `AppServices` with UI. `UI-less` services means that it could run in background, and `AppService` could also run in the foreground. You could refer this link to create [same process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process) AppService with out `EnterPoint`

Comment: But say App2 is an app with a same process AppService, can App1 still communicate with this AppService?

Comment: Sure, you could use AppServiceName to find target app's  AppService within App1

Comment: From your same process link: "With the introduction of in-process App Services, two running foreground applications can have a direct line of communication via an app service connection".  That seems to be exactly what I want :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would accept this answer if I could accept 2 :)